# Why can't whiltelist mint in candymachine UI?

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I am a beginner of metaplex.
What I want to achieve is to provide the feature of presale, which means white list!.
I followed the instruction in metaplex to set config.json.

```
}
    "whitelistMintSettings": {
    "mode" : { "neverBurn": true },
    "mint" : "xxxxKnH5",
    "presale" : true,
    "discountPrice" : 0.5
  },
```

Here, I set xxxxKnH5 as a member of whitelist and let him mint before public mint.
Then I update_candy_machine (this works fine).
But  in the UI interface, I always got error message:

```
There was a problem fetching whitelist token balance
Home.tsx:184 Error: failed to get token account balance: Invalid param: could not find account
```

Any idea of why I received this message and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the mint that you set a wallet or a SPL-token account?

Comment: oh yeah I realized that where I was wrong. 
but new question comes out
can not run ts-node gumdrop-cli.ts and received TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `"mint": "XXX...X",` line should contain a 0 decimals SPL-TOKEN.

Moreover, for airdropping it to users, you join the [Metaplex Discord](https://discord.gg/metaplex) server and check the `#airdrop-bash` thread. It contains a JS script that'll make airdropping the token to wallets alot easier:)